# ng-packgr entry point which is required doesn't exist

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I am migrating an Angular 8 library to Angular 9.  Once I migrated the library I can't build it as I get:  "Entry point shared-components/shared-services/ which is required by shared-components/date-time-pickers doesn't exists.".

It looks to me like it can't determine dependency order to build.   With Angular 8 I would see something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point 'shared-components'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
Bundling to FESM2015
Bundling to FESM5
Bundling to UMD
Minifying UMD bundle
Copying declaration files
Writing package metadata
Built cxone-components

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point 'shared-components/shared-services'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
Bundling to FESM2015
Bundling to FESM5
Bundling to UMD
Minifying UMD bundle
Copying declaration files
Writing package metadata
Built shared-components/shared-services
```

However, now get I something like this:

```
Building Angular Package
ERROR: Entry point shared-components/shared-services/ which is required by shared-components/date-time-pickers doesn't exists.
An unhandled exception occurred: Entry point shared-components/shared-services/ which is required by shared-components/date-time-pickers doesn't exists.
See "/private/var/folders/yc/jtk20z6s3ps5747jspv8gl1m0000gn/T/ng-zMfZrH/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Any thoughts?  Perhaps an issue with ng-package.json somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Doh!  One of my imports had a "/" at the end.  For example:

```
import {SvgIcon} from "shared-components/shared-services/"
```

It was ok under Angular 8 even though its not correct syntax.